# Why can't I use the Column data annotation with Entity Framework 5?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5, data-annotations

I want to use the `Column` data annotation as shown in the sample code below but the compiler (and also IntelliSense) do not seem to know that particular data annotation. I'm using EF 5 in Visual Studio 2010. I installed EF 5 using NuGet. The `Required` and `MaxLength` annotations are working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Model
{
    public class Destination
    {
        public int DestinationId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName="image")]
        public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
        public List<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column is in:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

the following code:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public IDbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "image")]
        public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

produces:

[image]